# Change language of actions-on-google websimulation or test google home in German

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I am using actions on google with api.ai. I am able to create a api.ai bot in a language other than English, but the web simulator of actions-on-google (https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/web-simulator) seems to work in English only? Is there any option to change the language there or a time schedule when other languages (in my case German) will be available in the simulator?

Currently testing a non English action is impossible, because the web simulator does not even forward requests if it doesnt understand their meaning on its own.

**Update 09/08/2017**: Google Home is now available in Germany, I just bought one. Isn't it possible to test my German actions with a google home device either?

Comment: have the same issue -.-

Comment: Right.  Actions on Google only supports EN-US today.  We will be adding other languages soon, stay tuned!

Comment: @BradAbrams I've started fiddling around with AoG today, and I also have created a German agent. I can't test an English one because my Phone is set to German, and I can't test the German one because I see no way of invoking the Agent on the phone. The simulator is also confused about the language. It tries, but isn't able to deal with the input.

Answer (score 3):

Yea -- sorry, you need to set your phone to US-English to test today.  We are working on making Actions on Google work for German but that will likely not be ready until later in the year.

Comment: What about adding English (Australian) ? Pretty annoying when it already speaks and understands the Australian accent but if you're writing code for it you have to set it to US-English and test with an American accent.

Comment: @brad-abrams Google Home was now released in Germany, I already got one. Is there any possibility to test my German actions on my real device since they are not working on a simultor?

Comment: Not yet.. but stay tuned. we are working on enabling this.

Comment: @BradAbrams same here. Have a German Google Home and cannot get my APIAI agent to run on it. It seems to work in Actions simulator, but the home device won't accept the english commands. And the simulator won't launch the Agent with German input (can set the locale to English only, all other entries are greyed out).

Answer (score 0):

AoG is now only available in en-GB an en- US. As Adams said you have to wait for a year.

Answer (score -2):

Any progress here?

While we could build a skill including linking accounts with Amazon Alexa in a day for de_DE, en_US and en_GB the same seems impossible in Google Home atm.