# Actions on Google - supported for German language?

Tags: actions-on-google

Google Assistant seems to be [rolling out to Android phones in Germany](http://stadt-bremerhaven.de/google-assistant-startet-in-deutschland-durch/) starting today (at least if they have the beta version of the Google app).

Are "Actions on Google" also supported in the German language, and if not, when is that going to come? I just tried to invoke some actions and it didn't work. Or was I just using the wrong phrase?

Comment: If you setup a Google Home with *German* device, you will be asked to change your device language to English. So currently there is no support.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010031/change-language-of-actions-on-google-websimulation-or-test-google-home-in-german

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actions on Google is now available in German, according to
https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/10/apps-for-google-assistant-new-languages.html

Comment: can this already be used by developers? I am wondering because there are only so few actions available - did nobody do it yet, or is it only possible for Google Partners? (like Otto etc.)

Comment: It is possible, the corresponding developer console is available at https://console.actions.google.com/ - I already submitted my action and am waiting for the review...

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues here:

1. Actions on Google are not (yet) supported on a Google Assistant besides the Google Home.
2. Actions on Google and Google Home are not (yet) supported in anything besides English.

**Update: May 2017**

At Google I/O, they made two announcements relevant to this:

1. Actions on Google are now available through the Assistant available on Android and iOS, not just Home.
2. Actions aren't (yet) available in anything besides en-US. They've announced that en-GB, French, and German will be available "later this year".

**Update: Oct/Nov 2017**

As @johan98 notes in his answer - German is now a supported language.

Comment: Is this only true for "US English" rather than any other kind of English? I have found no way to develop for British English Actions, but that have to change my Google Home's etc. language to US English.

Comment: I'm hearing some reports of this - but I'm not part of Google, so can't answer officially. Your best bet is to open a new StackOverflow question on the subject.

Comment: Are there any updates to this? I have Assisstant on a Nexus 5X, the language is set to German. I've created an Agent and set its language to German, but I see no way to test this on the phone, and the simulator isn't able to deal with German. The only way for me to test it is on api.ai itself, on the right "test" pane

Comment: Not much of an update, unfortunately, tho I've added it to the answer. German is scheduled for "later this year".